# Display Different Content For Different Countries?

Tags: multisite

I would appreciate your help on this issue.
I am creating a corporate website that will need 3 different iterations, one for each of the 3 locations served.

The preferred structure would be this: the www.xyz.com would be a landing page with a map for a user to select their location, once a user selects their location a sub-directory site is loaded: www.xyz.com/ca (for canada), www.xyz.com/usa (for USA) and www.xyz.com/sa (for south america).

Each of the 3 subdirectories will have a very similar site and will be in english but will have slightly different content tailored for each area. i.e. different product availability in each of the 3 locations and different content on the blog, etc. But the design and overall structure of the site will remain the same across all 3 iterations. For the Canadian iteration, I will need to add french as a togglable option as well (but french is not needed for the USA and SA iterations).

Should I just create one wordpress site and clone it to different sub-directories and tweek content for each (3 separate installs)? or is there a cleaner solution?

Are there SEO issues I should consider with these sub-directories?

Thoughts on this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Since you will have same content for about and product detail page irrespective to its translated version. So, obviously you might face seo penalty. As recently, Google algorithm has clarified a clear cut instructions for ecommerce websites that they can't use different pages for different languages or countries.

So, for your case, I would suggest you to use a multilingual language plugin. You may go through the documentation of WPML plugin. It enables you to create different language translated versions of your pages. There you may tweak your content too and it won't have any seo penalty.

Here is the link to plugin's official website
https://wpml.org/

> **Disclaimer:** I suggested this plugin because I have personally used it.
> This is neither an endorsement or promotion of the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wordpress multisite. This will enable you to use same installation for multiple sites and you can use your desired urls like www.xyz.com/ca (for canada), www.xyz.com/usa (for USA) and www.xyz.com/sa (for south america).
I think this will not have seo issues either  (this is my understanding  but you can cross check with any seo expert to confirm this).

Comment: Thank you. It seems the multisite adds a level of complexity that im not sure it makes sense here. Is there an easier, more straight forward way that you can suggest that would work in this case?

I've considered 3 separate installs of wordpress but i dont want sub domains. Although I do want the sub DIRECTORY structure.

Answer (score 0):

3 ways to solve your problem , all pro and cons  listed .
Please check link below : https://developers.google.com/search/docs/specialty/international/managing-multi-regional-sites#locale-specific-urls

Source: Managing multi-regional and multilingual sites (developers.google.com)